# Read file in a loop in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

I am supposed to write a small assembly "program" that simply reads a file using a loop and outputs the contents to STDOUT.

Now, I made a program that can read the file and unfortunately only outputs the first line. I also can't figure out how to use the loop.

This is my very first time working with assembly and I do it because I have to, not because I want to.

Here's my code:

```
section .text
   global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                  ;tell linker entry point
   ;open the file for reading
   mov eax, 5
   mov ebx, file_name
   mov ecx, 0             ;for read only access
   mov edx, 0777          ;read, write and execute by all
   int  0x80

   mov  [fd_in], eax

   ;read from file
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, [fd_in]
   mov ecx, info
   mov edx, 26
   int 0x80

   ; close the file
   mov eax, 6
   mov ebx, [fd_in]

   ; print the info 
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, info
   mov edx, 26
   int 0x80

   mov  eax,1             ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80              ;call kernel

section .data
file_name db './passwd'

section .bss
fd_out resb 1
fd_in  resb 1
info resb  26
```

Comment: Why do you reserve a byte for `fd_in` byte then read and write a dword?

Comment: No specific reason, it is just my first time doing something in assembly and I am a bit confused :D

Comment: Because that is definittely an error. Try reserving a dword using `resd` instead of `resb`.

Comment: Did that and I still get only the first line